# ExecuteStoreQuery with Dbcontext

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, objectcontext, dbcontext

I want to use `ExecuteStoreQuery` function of Entity Framework and I was wondered that my context variable didn't have `ExecuteStoreQuery` method.

So, I discovered that it's a method of `ObjectContext` class, but I've already used `DbContext` for my application.
I simply had tried to change `DbContext` with `ObjectContext`, but it brought some errors(for example, in ObjectContext isn't `OnModelCreating` method).

How can I use `ExecuteStoreQuery` with DbContext and if I can't, is any alternatives of `ExecuteStoreQuery` in DbContext?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

A `DbContext` is simply a wrapper around the `ObjectContext`.

You can still access the original `ObjectContext` by using [`IObjectContextAdapter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696590%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)

```
(dbContext as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;
```

Comment: I use this method successfully in my application.

Answer (score 38):

I want to add that I think now the correct method is:

```
dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<T>(string sql);
```

Comment: If you want to track changes to the returned objects, you should consider dbContext.tablename.SqlQuery<T>(...) where tablename is your collection name. (i.e. a DbSet)